# using lineinfile to insert line but not working as expected

Tags: ansible, centos7, ansible-module

I am using `lineinfile` to insert line in syslog file. Here is my syslog:

```
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
{
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

I would like to add `compress` and `delaycompress` after `missingok`. Here is my code:

```yaml
- name: "Adding compress line in /etc/logrotate.d/syslog"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
    insertafter: "^missingok"
    line: "    compress"
    firstmatch: yes
    state: present

- name: "Adding delaycompress line in /etc/logrotate.d/syslog"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
    insertbefore: "^sharedscripts"
    line: "    delaycompress"
    firstmatch: yes
    state: present
```

But its adding both at the end of the file(at last lines).
**Note**: I have added 4 spaces before `compress` and `delaycompress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the caret `^`, in a regex, matches the start of a string without consuming any characters.

And because you do have spaces before `missingok` and `sharedscripts`, your `insertafter` and `insertbefore` regex [are matching nothing](https://regex101.com/r/18L7aP/2).

To fix this, you can allow spaces and spaces only at the beginning of the line with the help of `\s` that matches any space, tab or newline character and of the star `*` that matches zero or more consecutive characters.

So the correct regex would be

- ```regex
  ^\s*missingok
  ```

  <sup>*[Test it here](https://regex101.com/r/18L7aP/3)*</sup>
- ```regex
  ^\s*sharedscripts
  ```

And the fix for your tasks would be:

```yaml
- name: "Adding compress line in /etc/logrotate.d/syslog"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
    insertafter: "^\\s*missingok"
    line: "    compress"
    firstmatch: yes
    state: present

- name: "Adding delaycompress line in /etc/logrotate.d/syslog"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
    insertbefore: "^\\s*sharedscripts"
    line: "    delaycompress"
    firstmatch: yes
    state: present
```

*Note that*, because Ansible is a Python application, [backslashes `\` have a special meaning and have to be escaped](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Comment: ansible failing at "^\s*missingok". verified in  yamllint.com

Comment: Indeed sorry my bad, for Ansible, in those regex, you need to double the backslashes, answer corrected.